# Make app icon on task bar have a transparent background (UWA)

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I am making a Universal Windows App and I want my apps icon on the task bar to have a transparent background so it isn't in a coloured box.

A lot of Microsoft's own stock apps are like this (Mail, Photos, Xbox etc) and I know it can be done because I did it by accident. But the icons I was using were too big and when I used correct sized ones it stopped working. I've tried using the old too large icons again and it still doesn't work.

[image]

Setting the tile background in the apps manifest just makes the background the users theme colour rather than actually transparent so I must of done something else, all of my assets for the Square 44x44 Logo of course have transparent backgrounds but I just get the tile background colour where there should be nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the "altform-unplated" qualifier in your icon's filename. For example:

```
SmallLogo.targetsize-32_altform-unplated.png
```

If you really want to be thorough... For Square44x44Logo in your manifest, you should have 6 versions of the icon (normal, high contrast black, and high contrast white, x3 for unplated versions) for each of the following target sizes: 16, 20, 24, 30, 32, 36, 40, 48, 60, 64, 80, 96, and 256.

For example, here's 256:

```
SmallLogo.targetsize-256.png
SmallLogo.targetsize-256_contrast-black.png
SmallLogo.targetsize-256_contrast-white.png
SmallLogo.targetsize-256_altform-unplated.png
SmallLogo.targetsize-256_altform-unplated_contrast-black.png
SmallLogo.targetsize-256_altform-unplated_contrast-white.png
```

That's a lot of PNGs.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this issue on windows 11 the "altform-lightunplated" qualifier.

SmallLogo.targetsize-256_altform-lightunplated.png

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast#:~:text=Shell%20light%20theme%20and%20unplated%20resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast#:%7E:text=Shell%20light%20theme%20and%20unplated%20resources)