# Wrong size of "unplated" icon is used

Tags: c#, uwp

I am writing a UWP app that includes an "unplated" icon at the 32x32 size (file name `Square44x44Logo.targetsize-32_altform-unplated.png`). I also have the same icon at the 24x24 size (file name `Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png`). I also have the same two sizes in non-"unplated" variants. However, when I build and run my app, the icon used in the taskbar (and *only* the taskbar) is of an incorrect size. The 24x24 icon is used, instead of the 32x32 icon, resulting in the icon appearing visibly smaller than the others in the taskbar. See picture below.

[image: Taskbar screenshot with incorrectly sized icon]

I have followed the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735562/make-app-icon-on-task-bar-have-a-transparent-background-uwa), to no effect.

Comment: Try to add the targetsize-88 and targetsize-176,which has higher resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 24x24 icon is used, instead of the 32x32 icon, resulting in the icon appearing visibly smaller than the others in the taskbar.

Your icon looks smaller than others might because it's rectangle. It has fewer number of pixels on the vertical, showing it in a "unplated" fashion would make it "looks" smaller.

Below is a screenshot of the zoomed image, it shows that your icon has the same width with another two icons.

[image: Figure-1]

In this case, I suggest you using the “plated” icon to see if your icon is the same size of others.

[image: Figure-2]

Windows 10 introduces an evolution of the existing scaling model. In addition to scaling vector content, there is a unified set of scale factors that provides a consistent size for UI elements across a variety of screen sizes and display resolutions.

For more information, see to [Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx).